# CSS parent div with children

Tags: css

I have a parent div, that holds three div's. They are basically columns. I need to remove the margin on the last one but can't get the right selector
HTML:

```
<div class="productContainer">
    <div class="productBox"></div>
    <div class="productBox"></div>
    <div class="productBox"></div>
 <!--/ productContainer --></div>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.productContainer {
    width: 980px;
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

How do you target the third child div of a parent? this should work no?
.productContainer > .productBox {
    width: 320px;
    height: 400px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
}

.produtContainer > .productBox nth:child(3) {
    margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I've posted a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786434/last-child-psuedo-class-selector-in-css-and-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you can use the :last-child selector, it's not going to work in any version of IE before 8. Generally what I do in this situation is add a last class to the last element in the list:

```
<div class="productContainer">
<div class="productBox"></div>
<div class="productBox"></div>
<div class="productBox last"></div>
```

And then add this rule below the .productContainer .productBox rule in the stylesheet:

```
.produtContainer .last {
margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree I still have to code for IE 7 so I have to do it this way. too bad. thx man.

Comment: It's funny that you said the same thing I did, except five minutes after me.  But you get credit for the answer :P

Answer (score 1):

```
.productContainter div:last-child
```

Comment: While being aware that this -`:last-child`- isn't available to IE < 9.

Comment: why doesn't .productContainer div:nth-child(3) work the same way? Due to IE i might have to just add a class to the last one.

Answer (score 0):

You can do :first-child or :last child to target the first and last element.

compatibility: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:last-child` selector for the rule

```
.productContainer div:last-child
{
    // rule
}
```

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure this looks for the last .productContainer, not the last div within it. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [last-child](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#last-child-pseudo) pseudo-selector in this case...

```
.productContainer > .productBox:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Note: This will not work in IE8 and older, as this is a part of CSS3.  For something more portable, you might want to try this...

```
<div class="productBox last"></div>

.productContainer > .productBox.last {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```