# Make the last category unbordered

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the last category have no bottom border, is there is any trick to done it without programming?

HTML & CSS:

```
<style>
#menu {
  border:1px red solid;padding:10px
}
#menu a {
  display:block;
  border-bottom:1px #000 dotted
}
</style>
<div id="menu">
  <p>MAIN MENU</p>
  <a>Computers</a>
  <a>Design</a>
  <a>Programming</a>
</div>
```

EXAMPLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/GLJWp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this, because `last-child` doesn't work in `IE`

**HTML**

```
<div id="menu">
    <p>MAIN MENU</p>
    <a>Computers</a>
    <a>Design</a>
    <a>Programming</a>
</div>​
```

**CSS**

```
#menu{
    border:1px red solid;padding:10px
}
#menu a{
    display:block;
    border-top:1px #000 dotted
}
```

The following would effect the first `a` after the `p`, `a:first-child` won't work in IE because `p` is the first child element

```
#menu p + a{
    border-top: none;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/GLJWp/5/).

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the `:last-child` pseudo class, which will apply the css rules only to the last item: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/firstchild.html

In this case you'd style the last link by:

```css
#menu a:last-child {border-bottom:none}
```

For supporting IE <9, have a look at [this beautifully horrible conditional stylesheet hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786434/last-child-psuedo-class-selector-in-css-and-internet-explorer/3786484).

Comment: `last-child` is not compatible with IE, at least not in 6-8, don't know about IE9.

Answer (score 1):

Done here: http://jsfiddle.net/GLJWp/2/