# Get (N-1)th last item on the page

Tags: css

I have a number of elements with specific css class on the page (let's say `item`). Is it possible to apply a css style on the (N-1)th `.item`? For example it there are 9 elements then I need to style 8th.

I know about `:nth-last-child(2)`. But it doesn't work in my case. It searches for CHILD elements but in my case elments are distributed between different parents.

**[jsFiddle of what I need](http://jsfiddle.net/fWRw8/3/)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the [child combinator selector (`>`)](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#child-combinators) with `body` along with @Zenith's solution

```
body > :nth-last-child(2)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fWRw8/2/

Comment: heh, sorry to steal your thunder

Comment: I need to apply style for the 2nd occurence of certain element on the page.

Comment: is the 2nd to last item nested in different ways?  what are you trying to solve?  if the item is sort of a moving target you'll likely need JavaScript

Comment: given your last jsfiddle, this fiddle has both a static CSS selector and a dynamic jQuery option that may help you http://jsfiddle.net/fWRw8/6/

Comment: so sad. I hoped to the last that it's possible with CSS only without JS. ok, thank you

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use the  `:nth-last-child(2)` selector to get the second-last element.

Here's a [**jsFiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/fWRw8/).

This isn't supported in older versions of IE, so [**here's a link to a quick hack**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3786484/1586880) which will get it working there too.

---

**Edit:** In regard to your specific use case, sadly it looks like there isn't any real solution using just CSS. My initial thoughts were `:nth-last-of-type` but as you're basing it on a class and with different parents that won't work. `:nth-last-child` is also based on the parent so that won't help either. Sadly, there is no class-related selectors similar to these either so I'm afraid to say you may have to do it via. jQuery.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It searches for CHILD elements but in my case elments are distributed between diferent parentsd.

Comment: This doesn't work in IE8 or earlier... is this going to be an issue for the OP?

Comment: @SergeyMetlov Ok, I'll try and work out a solution in regard to the edit now

Comment: @Zenith Hot ... never knew about this library!

Comment: @FeistyMango Oh wait, Selectivr only supports first-child and nth-child but not nth-last-child, I'll try to make an IE8 compatible alternative