# How to hack :last-child in IE 7 and 8?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How to make ":last-child" selector work in IE 7 and 8 ? 
Could anyone illustrate with a clear example on this ?

Comment: I think this would depend on your specific use case.

Comment: I hate to say that, but I think your solution is in [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3786484/1071486).

Comment: possible duplicate of [:last-child psuedo class selector in CSS and Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786434/last-child-psuedo-class-selector-in-css-and-internet-explorer)

Comment: I tried what you have suggested @abeaumet.It didn't work out.It seems that selectivizr.js works.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear about topic of your question, but I will try to answer

If you talk about usual menu, you can use `:first-child` selector with inverting border from `border-right` to `border-left`